# Youtube API - get views by cities?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

It is possible?

I read the documentation, there are examples of receiving the number of views by country, but I need the number of views by city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> regionCode string
>   The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return search results for videos that can be viewed in the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

The YouTube API only supports searching by region code that being [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html)

No you cant search by city.